# Split list of URLs without removing delimiter

Tags: pandas

I have a Panda dataframe with 2 columns URLs and comment like this : 
the values of URL column contain many URLs 
comment1  ==> https://www.example1.com/jjdf;https://www.example2.com/jjdss;https://www.example3.com/jjd;ddzd;https://www.example4.com/jj;

I want to split the values of column URLs into rows so I can get :

comment1 ==> https://www.example1.com/jjdf

comment1 ==> https://www.example2.com/jjdss

comment1 ==> https://www.example3.com/jjd;ddzd

comment1 ==> https://www.example4.com/jj

I have tried the code below it looks good cause it split by `;` but my problem is that there are some URLs which contain `;`, so when I split by `;http` to indicate the beginning of a URL, the result is not good cause it removes `http`. I hope to find a way to remove `;`, yet keeping `http`.

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.url.str.split(';http').tolist(), index=df.comment1).stack()
```

Comment: Would there be a way to transform `;http` into _something_ else, then split by this _thing_? Alternatively, you could continue splitting by `;http`, then add back `http` at the beginning of the URLs. Best would be not to use the same separator for comments within the URLs, and URLs in the list.

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to do something similar, the most straightforward way is to use a regular expression with a lookahead assertion:

```
df.url.str.split(';(?=http)')
```

The regular expression `;(?=http)` matches `;` when followed by `http` but does not include `http` in the match.

```py
import re
re.search(';(?=http)', ';ddzd;https') # => <re.Match object; span=(5, 6), match=';'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do something like this:

```
s = s.replace(";http", "|http")
comments = s.split("|")
```

I tried it using a single string, but you are using df.url.str so I think you are working with strings and it can be right.
Moreover, I used `|` because usually it doesn't appear in urls, but you should use any character that is not present in the urls.
So, first you should try `s.find("|")` and if there is that character, change it. With `find` if the character is not in the string it returns -1.
Finally, you should still have the final `;` that is not replaced before.

Hope it helps.